# How to calculate gps location on the move?

Tags: android, gps

I need to calculate Gps Location on the move and on deviation from certain position .I tried Using Driving Directions but it is deprecated any thing similar will be great.

Comment: Means you want your location in terms of latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think get location using gps frequently on the move would be feasible as it will consume lot off your battery power.., While for detecting a deviation, i think you need to calculate it manually on the basis of lat long.

Check out this for more info on Locations:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

and this,

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html

Answer (score 0):

```
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                location.getLatitude();
                            location.getLongitude()
                    // what you want to do
                }

                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                        Bundle extras) {
                    Toast.makeText(LocationInfoActivity.this,
                            String.valueOf("onStatusChanged " + provider),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    Toast.makeText(LocationInfoActivity.this,
                            String.valueOf("onProviderEnabled " + provider),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    Toast.makeText(LocationInfoActivity.this,
                            String.valueOf("onProviderDisabled " + provider),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };


            try {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 1, locationListener);

    // the 1 denotes meter (deviation)
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10000, 1,
                        locationListener);
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, 10000, 1,
                        locationListener);
            }

        }
```

reference:
     http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

Comment: Could you comment on why you use `String.valueOf("onStatusChanged " + provider)` instead of just using `"onStatusChanged " + provider`? Not only is the second way equivalent, it is also shorter, faster and IMO more readable.